# Template for checkboxList() and radioList() in Yii framework 2

Tags: yii2, checkboxlist

I have 4 radioList() in ActiveForm and I know how to customize one radioList()

like this:

```
    $form->field($model, 'type')->radioList(['A', 'B'], [
        'item' => function($index, $label, $name, $checked, $value){
             return 'template';

        }
    ])
```

I don't want to write this for every radioList() I have.
Is there a way to write this code in activeForm fieldConfig and apply for all radioList().

Comment: May be this will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38098791/yii2-config-global-template-for-all-forms-fields  Check Soju's answer.

Comment: thanks for your help